# GridView doesn't contain all of adapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I've made a GridView `mGridView` and an adapter `mAdapter` of 225 Views, and I set the adapter to the GridView. I also made a button so when I click on it does this:

```
Log.d("mAdapter.getCount()","" + mAdapter.getCount());
Log.d("mGridView.getCount()",""+mGridView.getCount());
Log.d("mGridView.getChildCount()",""+mGridView.getChildCount());
```

and there results are:

```
D/mAdapter.getCount()﹕ 225
D/mGridView.getCount()﹕ 225
D/mGridView.getChildCount()﹕ 180
```

This is a problem for me, because I need to use `mGridView.getChildAt(int position)` from `0` to `224`. Whenever I use `mGridView.getChildAt(180).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)` I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

It's saying that the child is `null`. But I don't know how to fix this so I can access every child that's in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

mGridView.getChildCount() would return the number of views visible at a time in the window. So say if my GridView has 5 columns and at a time only 10 could be displayed then mGridView.getChildCount() would return 50 (=5x10)

If you are trying to modify properties(say, backgroundColor) of a view at certain index using getChildCount API, you might probably check the first visible position(say, 25) using idxFirstVisiblePosition = mGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition(), then (idxFirstVisiblePosition + childCount - 1) would give you the maximum child index you could access and change properties for the current visible window.

Comment: So there's no way to change the children that aren't visible?

Comment: What is the point of changing UI for some widget that is not visible? You could change data source or style, the widget is bound to, and when widget is about to display it can always update itself with its data or even style such as backgroundColor or font you want to. what do you think?